# How to use SD Card in Android Emulator 1.5

Tags: android, sd-card

Hi I am new to Android. How to use System memory as a SD Card in the Android 1.5 Emulator.I am using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify SD card when creating AVD. Or you can specify -sdcard option in Eclipse Run Configuration - Target tab - Additional Emulator Command Line Options.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard